# utf8 encoding with Spring 4 + Tiles template + Freemarker

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker, tiles

I tried to integrate Spring 4 (4.3.0.), tiles 3 (3.0.7) and FreeMarker 2 (2.3.25-incubating), in templates definitions file I have:

```
<definition name="base-definition" template="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/layouts/layout.ftl" templateType="freemarker">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
</definition>

<!-- Home Page -->
<definition name="home" extends="base-definition">
   <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" />
   <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/home.jsp" />
</definition>
```

home.jsp:

```
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
....
```

layouts.ftl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
....
<title><@tiles.insertAttribute name="title" /></title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="site-content">
<@tiles.insertAttribute name="body" />
</section>
ľščťžýáíéúä
</body>
</html>
```

I have CustomTilesContainerFactory (extends BasicTilesContainerFactory) with registerAttributeRenderers function:

```
@Override
protected void registerAttributeRenderers(final BasicRendererFactory rendererFactory,
        final ApplicationContext applicationContext, final TilesContainer container,
        final AttributeEvaluatorFactory attributeEvaluatorFactory) {
    super.registerAttributeRenderers(rendererFactory, applicationContext, container, attributeEvaluatorFactory);

    FreemarkerRenderer freemarkerRenderer = FreemarkerRendererBuilder.createInstance()
            .setApplicationContext(applicationContext).setParameter("TemplatePath", "/")
            .setParameter("NoCache", "true").setParameter("ContentType", "text/html")
            .setParameter("template_update_delay", "0").setParameter("default_encoding", "UTF-8")
            .setParameter("number_format", "0.##########")
            .setParameter(SharedVariableLoaderFreemarkerServlet.CUSTOM_SHARED_VARIABLE_FACTORIES_INIT_PARAM,
                    "tiles," + TilesSharedVariableFactory.class.getName())
            .build();
    rendererFactory.registerRenderer(FREEMARKER_RENDERER_NAME, freemarkerRenderer);
}
```

I have CustomTilesInitializer (extends DefaultTilesInitializer) with createContainerFactory function:

```
@Override
protected AbstractTilesContainerFactory createContainerFactory(ApplicationContext context) {
    return new CustomTilesContainerFactory();
}
```

but in web-browsers, HTTP response header is OK:

```
text/html; charset=utf-8
```

but when I check properties of web page (mouse right-click), there is encoding "windows-1252", please, where is a problem, why there is not utf-8 ? And of course, there is problem with specials characters, in layouts.ftl there is "ľščťžýáíéúä" but in web-bowser is ?????ýáíéúä.

thanks!

Comment: I suspect that FreeMarker receives a `Writer` from the `HttpServletResponse` that encodes the text with some 8-bit chaset (typically ISO-8859-1), not with UTF-8. According to http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/ext/servlet/FreemarkerServlet.html you should have UTF-8 output encoding there, but perhaps the `Writer` was already created when the FreemarkerServlet is invoked, so the charset FreeMarker sets (UTF-8, hopefully) is silently ignored.

Comment: An addition to the above... you can try `setParameter("ResponseCharacterEncoding", "force UTF-8")` to be sure `FreemarkerServlets` indeed stets that charset (but yet again I suspect that it did it earlier too, but it's ignored as it's too late).

Comment: thanks for your comment, but `setParameter("ResponseCharacterEncoding", "force UTF-8")` is not working

Comment: You mean the output is still broken, as it was anticipated. So now you can be sure that `FreemarkerServlet` sets the response encoding correctly, so the other possible reason I mentioned is even more probable.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/index" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage(ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        return "home";
}
```

but, it is not very nice solution :-( neccessary to set content type in ALL request mapping functions ? :-(